# How to put in UIPickerView when editing UITextField

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uipickerview

I'm trying to implement some code such that when my UITextField is selected, a UIPickerView pops up instead of a normal keyboard. Currently, I have created a subclass of UITextField with `<UITextFieldDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate>`, but I am uncertain how to change the input view property of UITextField. Do I put

```
textField.inputView = pickerView;
```

in the `- (void)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method?

Comment: Actually setting that property anywhere you gonna change de input. Ex: You have an UITextField named "txtUser" in your .h, then in the viewdidload you set txtUser.inputview = pickerView and now you changed it.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer to the duplicate is not necessarily the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to subclass UITextField to do this. Just set it's inputView in your controller's viewDidLoad, and you should be good to go.  When the text field becomes first responder, the picker view will show up instead of the keyboard.

You probably want to make it so you take some action when the picker value changes.

Something like:

```
@interface MyViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField* dateField;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIDatePicker* picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    [picker addTarget:self
               action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.dateField.inputView = picker;
}


- (void) datePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker*)datePicker
{
    NSDateFormatter* aFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [aFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [aFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    self.dateField.text = [aFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
}

@end
```

Comment: When I implement this, I get a black screen with only my text field. The code works in popping up the date picker, but how do i get the rest of my view to show up?